# How to change HTML element for f:ajax

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, xhtml

I am wondering how I could change/replace the type of HTML element that is rendered when I am using an ajax component in jsf?

example:

```
                <f:ajax render="regionGroup" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{registerAction.cndOption.isTrue()}">
                            <h:outputLabel for="cndCivicCountryId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">#{messages['pi.label.country']}</h:outputLabel>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                                <h:message for="cndCivicCountryId" class="label label-danger" />
                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="cndCivicCountryId" value="#{registerAction.orgProfile.civicAddress.country}" required="true" disabled="true">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{pacUtils.getSortedList(referenceUtils.getCountryList(),localeSelector.locale)}" var="civicCountryCnd"
                                        itemLabel="#{civicCountryCnd.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" itemValue="#{civicCountryCnd}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
                        </ui:fragment>
                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{!registerAction.cndOption.isTrue()}">
                            <h:outputLabel for="intlCivicCountryId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">#{messages['pi.label.country']}</h:outputLabel>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                                <h:message for="intlCivicCountryId" class="label label-danger" />
                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="intlCivicCountryId" value="#{registerAction.orgProfile.civicAddress.country}" required="true"
                                    requiredMessage="#{messages['pi.msg.validation.registration.missingCountry']}" converter="selectItemToEntityConverter">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{messages['pi.label.selectOne']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{referenceUtils.getSortedIntlCountryList()}" var="civicCountry"
                                        itemLabel="#{civicCountry.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}" itemValue="#{civicCountry}">
                                    </f:selectItems>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </div>
                        </ui:fragment>
                    </div>
                </f:ajax>
                <h:panelGroup id="regionGroup">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h:outputLabel for="civicRegionId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">#{messages['pi.label.region']}</h:outputLabel>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <h:message for="civicRegionId" class="label label-danger" />
                            <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="civicRegionId" value="#{registerAction.orgProfile.civicAddress.region}" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="#{messages['pi.msg.validation.registration.missingRegion']}" converter="selectItemToEntityConverter"
                                disabled="#{registerAction.orgProfile!=null and registerAction.orgProfile.civicAddress.country==null}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{messages['pi.label.selectOne']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{registerAction.getSortedRegionsByCountry(registerAction.orgProfile.civicAddress.country)}" var="civicRegion" itemLabel="#{civicRegion.getDisplayName(localeSelector.locale)}"
                                    itemValue="#{civicRegion}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

for some reason turns into this:

```
 <span id="j_idt55:regionGroup">
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="j_idt55:civicRegionId" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Region, Province or State</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><select id="j_idt55:civicRegionId" name="j_idt55:civicRegionId" class="form-control" size="1">    <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
        <option value="1">Alberta</option>
        <option value="487">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="3">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="4">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="5">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
        <option value="7">Northwest Territories</option>
        <option value="6">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="8">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="9">Ontario</option>
        <option value="10">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="11">Quebec</option>
        <option value="12">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="13">Yukon</option>
      </select>
                        </div>
                    </div></span>
```

When viewing the source for the JSF XHTML page, as you can see from the full code above, the ajax tag turns into a span? this is problematic for me because inside this `<span>` is a `<div>` and therefore this comes up as a validation error in the W3C Source Validator (e.g.: Div element cannot be a child of Span element)

Comment: There is some relevant source code missing in your question. An f:ajax does not simply turn into a span.

Comment: it does in my code. I am using JBoss server, and i've updated the XHTML above to show the exact exact code, even if the other stuff was superlative...

Comment: What is the xhtml parent element of your f:ajax? And where is that xhtml element having `id="regionGroup"`?

Comment: oh wow! thanks that actually solved my issue... just post an answer with a link to f:ajax explained or something and i'll accept as the answer... h:panelGroup target was not set to block...

Comment: It's ok if you edit your question to contain that panelGroup, then you can post and accept an answer explaining the mistake. I have learned here that there's a use case for embedding elements in a <f:ajax/> which I didn't ever see or know is possible at all.

Comment: Done. Thanks again for the help :)